# What is the opposite of "Destination"

Tags: word-choice, antonyms

What is the antonym of the word destination. Here is some context:

Every train has a destination and a **____**?

I was thinking it might be origin but I've never encountered that word used in this context so I'm not sure - there might be a better word.

Comment: You should give time for answers to be given before accepting one. Your own reservations about the answer you accepted should tell you that it might not be the best. In this case, a later answer shows some excellent examples of how another word (origin) is commonly used to answer your request. You can undo your accept and reassign it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to a [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:amtrak.com%20origin%20destination), the word *origin* is used as the opposite of *destination* on several pages on the Amtrak web site.  Amtrak is the largest train operator in the United States.

Here are a few examples:

This [schedule](http://www.amtrak.com/ccurl/868/883/Trails-Rail-Summer-2014-Schedule.pdf) lists the **Origin** and "Destination" of various routes.

The [Interactive Route Atlas](http://www.amtrak.com/interactive-route-atlas) page says the following:

> Once you have selected **origin** and destination stations by one of the methods above, click on the 'Go' button to send your custom route request.

The [Multi-Ride Ten-Ride Ticket](http://www.amtrak.com/servlet/Satellite?SnippetName=IBLegacy&pagename=am/AM_Snippet_C/SnippetWrapper&ibsref=MultiRideTenRide) page says the following:

> Ten-ride tickets are valid for ten rides within a 45-day, 60-day or 180-day period depending on your **origin** and destination cities.

Comment: station of origin would be more specific.

Answer (score 6):

At least for marine shipping, "port of origin" is traditionally used. I think origin is appropriate for trains too.

Comment: What has a port to do with a train?

Answer (score 2):

"Source" can be used at most of the places I guess.
Origin, Start, Beginning etc. would also be fine.

Comment: This is best for math too since origin usually stands for a reference point, such as (0, 0).

Comment: This is what I would use in computing as well.